# How to trim string from char like "%" to end C#

Tags: c#

How i can trim string from char to end? Something like this:

```
32.6% of 3.07MiB at  5.71MiB/s ETA 00:00
```

and need output like this

```
32.6
```

Comment: What have you researched so far? whats not working for you, what error are you getting, what dont you understand?

Comment: Tried string.Trim (but its not working well, bcs number is difference eg. 0, 32, 100 etc.

Comment: If you read the documentation, `string.Trim` does a completely different thing. Have you read the documentation on `string.Substring`, and `string.IndexOf` ?

Comment: That's not trimming. [Trimming is removing all instances of a given set of a characters from the start/end/both ends of a string (typically whitespace).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `string result = "32.6% of 3.07MiB at  5.71MiB/s ETA 00:00 ".Split('%')[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Compared to the suggestion of using Split, I would suggest

```
value.Substring( 0, value.IndexOf( '%'))
```

... because it does not require allocating an array, which  Split does.

Comment: Need to check for IndexOf < 0 there.

Answer (score 0):

What about like this:

```
string str = "32.6% of 3.07MiB at  5.71MiB/s ETA 00:00 ";
         if (str.Contains('%'))
            {
                int index = str.IndexOf('%');
                string result = str.Substring(0, index);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
```